# Matlab and "Error while evaluating UIcontrol callback"

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab file that I can't post here (3000 lines) which contains a lot of functions which are used from a GUI.

I am working with matlab file that contains the 3000 lines which has so many functions for design GUI

when I am using `Function A` that function which are related to uses the several other functions and make it as for loop that run many time `function A (1600-2000)` times of iterations through taking a long time.

when I reached at 400-500 Matlab gives me

`error : "Error while evaluation UIcontrol callback"`

I must to kill the existing process and then exit Matlab and run again from the previous iteration which give the error. So my problem is not based on the function call but it may comes based on memory or may be temporary memory.

Does it possible to increase the temporary memory uses by Matlab ?

I increase the preference "Java heat memory" at maximum but this preference change nothing to my problem.

Is there any way to solve this issue ?

A part of the script :

```
function CalculateManyOffset % It's Function A on this topic

mainfig         = FigHandle;
parameters      = get(mainfig,'UserData');

dbstop if error

NumberofProfiles = str2double(get(parameters.NumberofProfilesBox,'string'));
step = str2double(get(parameters.DistBetweenProfilesBox,'string'));

Alphabet=('A':'Z').';
[I,J] = meshgrid(1:26,1:26);
namered = [Alphabet(I(:)), Alphabet(J(:))];
namered = strvcat(namered)';

nameblue = [Alphabet(I(:)), Alphabet(J(:))];
nameblue = strvcat(nameblue)';

apostrophe = '''';

SaveNameDisplacementFile = [get(parameters.SaveNamebox,'string'),'.txt'];

a=0;
icounter = 0;
StartBlue = str2double(get(parameters.bluelinebox,'String'));
EndBlue = StartBlue + NumberofProfiles;
StartRed = str2double(get(parameters.redlinebox,'String'));
EndRed = StartRed + NumberofProfiles-15;
for i = StartBlue:step:EndBlue;
    icounter = icounter +1;
    jcounter = 0;
for j=StartRed:step:EndRed;  
    jcounter = jcounter +1;
    opthorz = [];
    maxGOF = [];
    a=[a(1)+1 length(StartRed:step:EndRed)*length(StartBlue:step:EndBlue)]
    %
    if a(1) >= 0 && a(1) <= 20000
    BlueLineDist  = 1*i;
    parameters.bluelinedist = i;
    RedLineDist = 1*j;
    parameters.redlinedist = j;
    parameters.i = icounter;
    parameters.j = jcounter;
    set(mainfig,'UserData',parameters,'HandleVisibility','callback'); % To update variable parameters for the function which use them (downside : BlueLine, RedLine, GetBlueProfile, GetRedProfile, CalculateOffset)
    BlueLine;
    RedLine;
    GetBlueProfile;
    GetRedProfile;
    CalculateOffset;        
% Now, reload variable parameters with new value calculate on previous functions
    mainfig         = FigHandle;
    parameters      = get(mainfig,'UserData');
    opthorz = parameters.opthorz;
    name = [num2str(namered(:,jcounter)'),num2str(nameblue(:,icounter)'),apostrophe];
    namefid2 = [num2str(namered(:,jcounter)'),' - ',num2str(nameblue(:,icounter)'),apostrophe];
    Distance = [num2str(RedLineDist),' - ',num2str(BlueLineDist)];
    maxGOF = parameters.maxGOF;
            % Create file with all displacements
    if a(1) == 1;   
        fid2 = fopen(SaveNameDisplacementFile,'w');         
        fprintf(fid2,['Profile red - blue\t','Distance (m) between profile red - blue with fault\t','Optimal Displacement\t','Goodness of Fit\t','20%% from Goodness of Fit\t','Minimal Displacement\t','Maximal Displacement \n']);
        fprintf(fid2,[namefid2,'\t',Distance,'\t',num2str(opthorz),'\t',num2str(maxGOF),'\t',num2str(parameters.ErrorGOF),'\t',num2str(parameters.ErrorDisp(1,1)),'\t',num2str(parameters.ErrorDisp(1,2)),'\n']);
    elseif a(1) ~= b(end);
        fid2 = fopen(SaveNameDisplacementFile,'a');
        fprintf(fid2,[namefid2,'\t',Distance,'\t',num2str(opthorz),'\t',num2str(maxGOF),'\t',num2str(parameters.ErrorGOF),'\t',num2str(parameters.ErrorDisp(1,1)),'\t',num2str(parameters.ErrorDisp(1,2)),'\n']);
    else
        fid2 = fopen(SaveNameDisplacementFile,'a');
        fprintf(fid2,[namefid2,'\t',Distance,'\t',num2str(opthorz),'\t',num2str(maxGOF),'\t',num2str(parameters.ErrorGOF),'\t',num2str(parameters.ErrorDisp(1,1)),'\t',num2str(parameters.ErrorDisp(1,2))]);
        fclose(fid2);
    end       
end
end
end
```

Comment: Can you post any more information about your Function A? Can you run the function outside of a GUI and it works? What does MATLAB do when you hit the error if you run `>> dbstop if error` first?

Comment: I will try `dbstop if error` and post here the result.

I never try to run the function outside of the GUI because I put some values on it which are use on variable in function.

the function A create some figures which are saves by `print` function.

Comment: I write `dbstop if error` and the error occur again : `Error while evaluating UIControl Callback`. And it's not write 'busy' but 'Stopped in debugger' (on the lower left corner).

I don't have more information with `dbstop if error`

Comment: if it was a memory issue Matlab would indicate it in the error message. Please give your full exact error message (instead of only its location).

Comment: I just have `Error while evaluating UIControl Callback` as you can see here : http://hpics.li/10bbe53 (screenshot)

Comment: dbstop if error will put you in debug mode when you hit an error. This means you can look at he exact line of code that the error occurred on and try to see what is going on.

Comment: Can you give us some information about the callback function you think? Maybe sounds if there could be some problem with the input arguments. Is the code to this callback function short enough to write it in the question?

Comment: I add a part of the script (Function A) but several function are call in this one.

Comment: I think the problem don't come from the script but from a Matlab preference. Because when the script bug and display `Error while evaluating UIcontrol callback` I can't do anything even exit figures or Matlab. I must to kill the Matlab process to exit it.
After, I restart Matlab and run the script starting from the previous iteration which bug later. And it's work, but 400-500 iterations later, the same error appear.

It's not about time because even if the script is fast or slow, at 400 - 500 iterations the `error` appears.